# blur lines on ubuntu 16.04 and intel D graphics 530

Tags: unity, display, intel-graphics

I have this new laptop with Intel Ci7 6700HQ with Intel HD Graphics 530. The display shows blur lines randomly on the screen. They are not permanent either. Please see the screenshot. The tabs of chrome browser in the center are blur. This blurring disappear when I move the mouse over the blur area. I did not have this issue on Win 10 pre-installed on the laptop. [image]

Ok here is the out of command `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry for really late response.